# dockerfile: not able to run command

Tags: docker

Docker version 1.0.1, build 990021a

I am trying to run following command in via dockerfile and seeing error

```
FROM centos:6
MAINTAINER averma <some@somemail.com>
RUN yum -y install wget svn
WORKDIR /usr/local/src
RUN rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
RUN wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
RUN rpm -Uhv rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
RUN yum -y install java-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64
RUN mkdir -p /u001/tomcat-apps/
ENV PATH /u001/tomcat-apps
RUN chown root:root /etc/bootstrap.sh
RUN chmod 700 /etc/bootstrap.sh
CMD ["/etc/bootstrap.sh", "-d"]
EXPOSE 8280
```

Error:

```
Step 13 : RUN chown root:root /etc/bootstrap.sh
     ---> Running in a48ef57822bd
    /bin/sh: chown: command not found
```

I used the same file and it was working fine. my base container is official centos6.6

Comment: I think we need to see the full Dockerfile

Comment: added the remaining docker file content

Answer (score 0):

You've broken the path, by setting:

```
ENV PATH /u001/tomcat-apps
```

So the container can't find any binaries, including `chown`. I guess you meant:

```
ENV PATH $PATH:/u001/tomcat-apps
```